# Disqus comment links on ajax website

Tags: java, disqus

So Disqus will only work on a dynamically refreshing page if you use hashbangs in your url.  So I modified my schema to look like this for example:

```
http://domain.com/reader/#!23
```

And that's fine, but when someone posts a comment, the link to the comment will look like this (from Disqus):

```
http://domain.com/reader/#!23#comment-249780218
```

When you click that link, the page loads fine, but no comments load.  Now if you just navigate straight to the first link, all comments load.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The '#' character is the marker for a fragment identifier in a URL.  A URL with more than one '#' is malformed.  So maybe you should try %-escaping the 2nd '#' character.

---

Why is that a problem on the disqus side?  Surely the problem is on your side ... that you are not escaping the 2nd '#' character.

Did you take a look at the source of some disqus page in which one of these comment links is displayed?  Is the 2nd '#' escaped in the link's 'href' attribute?  (If not, that's a disqus bug ...)

Comment: Guess that explains that. I am still a bit at a loss though b/c the problem is on the disqus side.  they require the hashbang to be able to load comments on a dynamic page, but then they tack on the second hash.